# How to register same event for different times ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, cron

I'm building an auction web app in ASP.NET MVC and I have an auction expiration time for each auction item. It means whenever that time will reach the auction will be ended for that particular item and a flag of **Auction Ended**  will be set in the database for the particular auction item.

Now I'm struggling with how I can initialize a timer or background job or something like that for each auction item so whenever the expiration time will reach it will change the item status to **Auction Ended** immediately in the database.

I have worked with Schedulers and Timers in the Winforms but I think it's not a better idea to have a separate scheduler for each auction item.

Looking forward to any suggestion and idea.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can handle this "On Demand".  Essentially when someone makes any request against a particular auction, the data for that auction is pulled.  At this time you would check the auctionEndsAt datetime, and if the auction is over but the bit is not yet set in the db, set that flag.  For an active auction, use a js timer for displaying the update to the view.  Since the auction data is checked whenever any action is requested against that auction, you can prevent those late requests.

Comment: Actually, I have implemented SignalR for real-time notification, so for example if an auction is going to expire in 2 mins and the user is watching the time on the website so after the two mins, that auction should be automatically ended so that they can't place a bid and a notification to all the active users will be sent who were the participants of that auction.